# Top navigation bar with truncated hamburger menu in mobile website

Tags: bug, design, top-bar, mobile-web

When using the mobile version of Stack Overflow, a partially off-screen hamburger-menu with no obvious functionality can be seen on the very left of the top navigation bar.

[image]

Clicking on it has exactly the same effect as clicking on the Stack Overflow logo: it opens the menu `Current Community`.
In fact, at this point, the Stack Overflow logo moves slightly to the left and "pushes" the hamburger menu completely off-screen. Closing the menu will restore the situation as shown in the first screenshot.

[image]

It's only a minor issue, but could the hamburger menu please be removed?

Comment: What's the purpose of hamburgers anyway when you can have cheeseburgers.